# Laravel Redirect URL Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want redirect url from /topic/{title} to /topic/{category}/{title}.
So I try to registered this in routes:

```
Route::get('/topic/{title}',function(){
    return redirect()->action('/topic/{category}/{title}','DetailController@index');
});
```

But I got error

> Action App\Http\Controllers/topic/{category}/{title} not defined.

Anyone can help me about the routes?
Thanks for advance.

This is my Controller

```
class DetailController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index($section=0,$title = 0)
        {
            $detail = DB::table('t_artikel')
                ->join('t_section', 't_section.id_section', '=', 't_artikel.id_section')
                //->join('t_kolom', 't_kolom.id', '=', 't_artikel.penalar')
                ->where('publish', '=', 'Y')
                ->where('parent_id', '=', 0)
                ->where('tgl_pub', '<=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->where('t_artikel.urltitle', '=', $title)
                ->select('t_artikel.*', 't_section.*', 't_artikel.urltitle as urlartikel')
                ->first();
            $kategori = DB::table('t_section')
                ->where('id_supsection', '=', 0)
                ->where('status', '=', 1)
                ->orderBy('position', 'asc')
                ->whereNotIn('id_section', [34])
                ->select('t_section.*')
                ->get();
            $page = 'Detail';
            return view ('detail.detail',
                ['detail'       => $detail,
                 'kategori'     => $kategori,
                 'page'         => $page          
                 ]);
      }
```

Comment: please, can you share with us what's in your DetailController@index?
Also, how many categories could have a topic? Is possible to exist 2 topics with the same title (but with different categories) ? In that case, if you write /topic/title what's the behaviour you'll expect?

Comment: fyi, the old url's already shared so I want to redirect the old url's (topic/mytitle)to my new url's(topic/mycategory/mytitle) without share the new url's, and if there is user visits my old url's so it automatically redirect to the new url's. category and title are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions),

> If your controller route requires parameters, you may pass them as the second argument to the  action method

So, you need to pass the parameters like this:

```
return redirect()->action(
    'DetailController@index', ['category' => <enter_value>, 'title' => <enter_value>]
);
```

Comment: ummm, but I want the link redirect to /topic/category/title

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use 2 routes and 2 controllers. One handles the details of the topic and the other one handles the redirect of the "old" url.

For example: the user will visit "/topic/title" that is handled by a controller that will recognize topic and category, then will use the

```
public function handleTopic($title){
    // the code here will recognize topic and category
    // and will just provide the stuff to show the right page
    // in the end will redirect to that controller
    return redirect()->action('DetailController@index', ['category' => $category, 'title' => $title]);
}

public function index($stuffYouNeed){
    // retrieve the rest of data you need to show the page
    // you already know the title and category (cause of previous controller)
    // in the end return the view with data
    return view ('detail.detail',['data' => $data]);
}
```

In your routes you'll have to add one route and edit the existing one like:

```
Route::get('topic/{title}', 'DetailController@handleTopic')->name('handleTopic');

Route::get('topic/{category}/{title}', 'DetailController@index')->name('showTopic');
```

It's not tested cause atm i don't have a laravel env set up in local. But i think it should work. Let me know

Edit: I forgot to explain why you see the error

> Action App\Http\Controllers/topic/{category}/{title} not defined.

You are using the redirect incorrectly

```
Route::get('/topic/{title}',function(){
return redirect()->action('/topic/{category}/{title}','DetailController@index');
});
```

You can only provide an action controller, not a route. And the destination route have to exist. So the right use is:

```
return redirect()->action('Controller@action');
```

Anyway, you should split logic from routes. You have controllers for that... even for really short blocks of code. It will keep everything in order and clear. In your route file you should have ONLY routes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I found my way after modified. and this is the code:

```
Route::get('/topik/{title}',function($title){    
    $article = DB::table('t_artikel')
            ->join('t_section', 't_section.id_section', '=', 't_artikel.id_section')          
            ->where('publish', '=', 'Y')
            ->where('parent_id', '=', 0)
            ->where('tgl_pub', '<=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->where('t_artikel.urltitle', '=', $title)
            ->select('t_artikel.*', 't_section.urltitle as urltitlesec', 't_artikel.urltitle as urlartikel')
            ->first();
     $kategori = $article->urltitlesec;
     return redirect("/topik/{$kategori}/{$title}");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a URI, then *don’t* use `redirect()->action()`; use `redirect()->to()` instead:

```php
Route::get('/topic/{title}', function ($title) {
    $category = ''; // Get category some how

    return redirect()->to("/topic/{$category}/{$title}");
});
```